# Excel plot diagram with variable time points

Tags: excel, plot, charts, time-series, diagram

I'm trying to plot a diagram with varying timestamps (the diff of timepoints are variable). And I would like to show the variability in the X axis, so the distance of timestamps be reflected on the diagram. For instance, my data is like this (time points in `milliseconds`):

```
time value
---------
0 102
3 104
15 121
29 123
59 111
78 110
```

So once I plot it, I want the distance of timestamps be shown accordingly, like the plot below.

[image]

How can I do that? I have thousands of points like this.

Comment: This looks like a scatterplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you highlight your data set (including the headings), you can go to **Insert** and then click the dialog box launcher to get chart options.

(see the blue square to the right)
[image]

From there, you'll get a popup screen like this:
[image]

You can then go through and see what chart will work best for you. You'll be able to modify your data, colors, etc. from the new *Design* and *Format* tabs that appear on the ribbon when you click anywhere within the newly created chart.

**I'm running Office 365 ProPlus, but the steps are similar in other versions of Excel*

Comment: Thanks. Yes scatter chart is key!